# Rails sending emails between users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I'm working on an app where I want the users to be able to send messages between each other via email. I checked Action Mailer but it allows me to send emails from my application not between two users.

I was thinking of doing it by displaying the user email so they can click on it and send that user email. Any idea about how i should do this?

Comment: You might want to use APIs for this, for example [Mandrill](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mandrill-api-ruby) or [Sendgrid](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

If you're satisfied with only email-link, then you can just use [mailto](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-mail_to) url-helper. It'll open your local default email-client.

For ex.

```
mail_to "where.to.send@mail.com", "Link name", cc: "send.here.as.cc@mail.com", subject: "Yep, it works"
```

will produce

```
<a href="mailto:where.to.send@mail.com?cc=send.here.as.cc%40mail.com&amp;subject=Yep%2C%20it%20works">Link name</a>
```